# How do you find the user-selected install path in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to get the path that the user chose to install my application into.

If I set `CreateAppDir=yes` and set a `DefaultDirName=C:\MyApp\` the user can change it to some other directory.  After they do this, I need to know which directory they chose on the next install wizard step.  How can I get this value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`{app}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app) constant. The reference describes it as:

> The application directory, which the user selects on the **Select
> Destination Location** page of the wizard. For example: If you used
> `{app}\MYPROG.EXE` on an entry and the user selected `"C:\MYPROG"` as the
> application directory, Setup will translate it to
> `"C:\MYPROG\MYPROG.EXE"`.

Optionally you can use the [`WizardDirValue`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizarddirvalue) function. This one is described as:

> Returns the current contents of the edit control on the **Select
> Destination Location** page of the wizard.
>
> Unlike `ExpandConstant('{app}')`, this function will not fail if called
> after the wizard is shown but prior to the user selecting a directory.
> Rather, it will return the default directory name.

Comment: Ahhh - I think {app} is what I need.  I looked at that previously and I guess I read it differently because it didn't seem like what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: And UUUGG - I just realized I use it all over the place and it didn't even dawn on me that's what it was doing.  DOH! :P