# Retrieve installation path in uninstaller

Tags: inno-setup

I want to display installation path on uninstaller window.

[image]

How to automatically remember and place there the name of the folder chosen for the installation? Is this possible?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`{app}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app). In Pascal Script, your can resolve it using the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant):

```pascal
Edit.Text := ExpandConstant('{app}');
```

---

Note that contrary to the installer, you cannot use the [`WizardDirValue` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizarddirvalue).

For solutions in the installer, see [How do you find the user-selected install path in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28349106/850848)