# Get the path in the wpSelectDir before {app} is set Inno Setup

Tags: window, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to get the path of the install directory, when the user clicks on *Next*, when I'm in the `wpSelectDir` of Inno Setup.

I need to check the path, because I need to verify the path, and if it's not correct, I won't let the user continue.

My problem is that the constant `{app}` is not set yet, because it will be set after the `wpSelectDir` and I'm still in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WizardDirValue` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizarddirvalue):

> Returns the current contents of the edit control on the *Select Destination Location* page of the wizard.
>
> Unlike `ExpandConstant('{app}')`, this function will not fail if called after the wizard is shown but prior to the user selecting a directory. Rather, it will return the default directory name.

---

It's more idiomatic than the `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text`.

Though internally it does nearly the same:

```pascal
RemoveBackslashUnlessRoot(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text)
```

---

See also [How do you find the user-selected install path in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28349106/850848)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this....

```
procedure onDirChange(Sender: TObject);
var
    currentDir: String;
begin
    currentDir := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
    // your validation goes here....
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    WizardForm.DirEdit.onChange := @onDirChange;
end;
```

The `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text` returns the current value in the `DirEdit` Text Box. The procedure `onDirChange` is called everytime the text in the dirEdit text box changes. You can use this value to perform your validations.