# Inno Setup, install only on a non existent directory

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to not permit the installation on an existent directory or at least a non-empty one.

Right now I am using this workaround just to check if the program was installed in the directory chosen by the user but this doesn't work if it is a directory where the program was not installed or a non empty one.

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(PageId: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
    if (PageId = wpSelectDir) and  FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\some_app_file')) then
    begin
        MsgBox('Warning message, cannot continue.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
        exit;
    end;
end;
```

I have the `DirExistsWarning=yes` directive but it's not enough.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So why don't you use `DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}'))`?

Comment: I was thinking something similar and I am using a workaround that it's related to this, but I had some doubts after I read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016945/399637  . Do I have to use `{app}` or `WizardDirValue` ?

Comment: Once on the `wpSelectDir`, both behave identically.

Comment: answer the question, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}'))` to check for an existence of the selected directory.