# Using scripting constant in DirExistsWarning and other directives

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to script the Constant `DirExistsWarning` but it returns an error:

> Value of [Setup] section directive "DirExistsWarning" is invalid.

My simplified script is as such:

```pascal
...
[Setup]
DirExistsWarning={code:showFolderExists}
...
[Code]
{ hide folder exists Dialog when this version is being uninstalled }
function showFolderExists(Param: String): String;
begin
    Result := 'yes';
end;
```

Can this constant not be scripted? If so, is there an accessible list of constants that can be or cannot be scripted? 
I also tried returning a boolean value without much success.

Thank you

Comment: Correct. This directive is for compilation time and cannot be scripted by code (at this time).

Comment: Thanks @TLama, can I ask if there is any way to control this behavior on ```wpSelectDir```? I guess otherwise I'll implement a manual MsgBox in ```NextButtonClick()```.

Comment: For that, see [Inno Setup, install only on a non existent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55721409/850848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`DirExistsWarning` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_direxistswarning) *cannot be scripted*, because its value cannot include "constants" (sic).

Directives that can include "[constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)" (what includes "[scripted constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants)") have that explicitly mentioned in their documentation.

For example the documentation for [`AppId` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) says:

> The value may include constants.

---

For your actual problem see
[Inno Setup, install only on a non existent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55721409/850848).