# How to find destination location during upgrade

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a constant / installer variable / function available to find the destination location during upgrade ?
I checked [How do you find the user-selected install path in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349106/how-do-you-find-the-user-selected-install-path-in-inno-setup) but both `WizardDirValue()` as well as `ExpandConstant('{app}')` throw an exception when used during upgrade. I understand that the `Inno Setup: App Path` key under uninstall registry key can be read to find the location during upgrade. Wanted to understand if there is any alternative ? Trying to use `WizardForm.DirEdit.Text` also throws exception

Comment: It's not true that `WizardDirValue` or `app` constant throw an exception during upgrade. They may throw an exception in specific situations. You have to show us how exactly are you using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In event function UpdateReadyMemo constant app is accessible.

```
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var
    s: String;
begin
    s := ExpandConstant('{app}');
    MsgBox(s, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := MemoComponentsInfo
end;
```

UpdateReadyMemo is automatically called just before ready to install dialog. Its return value will be shown in this dialog.

Comment: Aah.... I tried `ExpandConstant('{app}')` before psoting the question but did not realize that I was also accessing another control from the wpSelectDir page during upgrade in the code and that it was also problematic when the page was skipped for the upgrade case.

Comment: There is no problem using `{app}` if `wpSelectDir` is skipped, but you can still only do so strictly after `wpSelectDir` would have been shown or in its `NextButtonClick` (which is also still called even if skipped).